# Detectar o clique sobre um iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

Tenho um iframe:

```
<div class="recebe_iframe">
    <iframe class="caixa_iframe" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dfsdfsdf" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Queria com jquery detectar quando um usuário clica sobre esse iframe do youtube ou mesmo nessa div `recebe_iframe`. Pode ser quando o usuário clica dentro dele, em qualquer lugar, pode ser em play, pause, volume, não importa... apenas detectar esse clique.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar:

```
$( "recebe_iframe" ).click(function() {
  //código
});
```

Como não ficou muito claro o que você está querendo, isso pode te algum norte.

Exemplo:

```js
$( "p" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).slideUp();
});
```

```css
p {
    color: red;
    margin: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  p:hover {
    background: yellow;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>click demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>First Paragraph</p>
<p>Second Paragraph</p>
<p>Yet one more Paragraph</p>

 
</body>
</html>
```

Referência: [jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

Comment: Oi, obrigado pela resposta, mas não é bem isso. Tenho o iframe do Youtube. Queria detectar quando o usuário clica dentro dele, em qualquer lugar, pode ser em play, pause, volume, não importa... apenas detectar esse clique.

Answer (score 1):

O click não da para capturar, o que da para fazer é verificar quando houve um "hover" na div que o frame está envolvido.

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
    var frame = -1;
    $('iframe').hover( function() {
        alert('hover')
    }, function() {
        frame = -1
    });
        $(window).blur( function() {
        if( frame != -1 ) 
            alert('desapareceu'); 
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
></script>
<div class='banner'>
    <iframe src='http://somedomain.com/whatever.html'></iframe>
<div>
```